# Can the image of a continuous, but nowhere-differentiable, function be a borel set?

Tags: measure-theory

I apologize if this question is short, but in essence, I wonder:

Does there exist any function, $f(t): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$, which is continuous but nowhere differentiable, such that the set $$\{f(t):t\in[0,1]\} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a compact set, so it's always Borel. Therefore the question reduces to whether or not there is a continuous nowhere differentiable function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$, which I don't believe I need to persuade you of. If you substitute $t\in[0,1]$ with, say, $t\in\Bbb R$, then you can write the set as $$\{f(t)\,:\,t\in\Bbb R\}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\{f(t)\,:\, t\in[-n,n]\}$$

which is a $F_\sigma$ set.

Comment: Yes, this is very obvious in hindsight. I apologize. May I ask whether a similar case is possible for nowhere continuous functions?

Comment: @JayZenvia Well, $1_\Bbb Q$ has image two points and it's nowhere continuous. Ironically, I would say that finding a nowhere continuous function with non-Borel image is more challenging. My guess: I think that with AC you can choose a Vitali set $V\subseteq[0,1]$ such that $\overline V=[0,1]$. If you have that, then $f(x)=\begin{cases}3&\text{if }x\notin V\\ x&\text{if }x\in V\end{cases}$. The image is not measurable because it's $V\cup\{3\}$; Vitali sets have empty interior and, together with $\overline V=[0,1]$, this guarantees tht $f$ is nowhere continuous on $[0,1]$.